# How can I restore the previous activity after restarting the app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have this language  settings on my app. After I set my desired language and restarting, the language didn't apply, rather setting back to the default language. Can anyone help me with this?

Here's my code

```js
import java.util.Locale;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;


public class AndroidLocalize extends Activity {

  Spinner spinnerctrl;
  Button btn;
  Locale myLocale;

  @
  Override
  public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.androidlocalize);
    spinnerctrl = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinnerctrl.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView <? > parent, View view,
        int pos, long id) {

        if (pos == 1) {

          Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
              "You have selected Filipino", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
          Intent nextForm = new Intent(".MainActivity");
          startActivity(nextForm);
          setLocale("tl");


        } else if (pos == 2) {

          Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
              "You have selected English", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
          Intent nextForm = new Intent(".MainActivity");
          startActivity(nextForm);
          setLocale("en");

        }
      }

      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView <? > arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }
    });
  }

  public void setLocale(String lang) {

    myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    Intent refresh = new Intent(this, AndroidLocalize.class);
    startActivity(refresh);

  }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

when AndroidLocalize created, you should check for configuration, if exists then using that confguration start MainActivity.

what you are doing is after setting you are starting same activty again, since on create method you are not checking set config it will display the default one

solution, 
1. check config oncreate
2. set locale first and then call startActivity